# Django AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model that has not been installed

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

I am working on a django project which requires login through email or phone number. This is my models.py file:

```
class NewUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex =r'^\+?1?\d{9,14}$', message="Phone number must be in the format: '+999999999'. Upto 14 digita allowed.")
    phone = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=15, unique=True)
    first_login = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    about = models.TextField(_(
        'about'), max_length=500, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    
    #objects = CustomAccountManager()
    #objects = EmailOrPhoneModelBackend()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
    
    def get_email_field_name(self):
        if self.email:
            return self.email
        else:
            return self.phone
    
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True
    
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
    
    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.is_active
     
    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.is_admin
```

To authenticate by using both email and phone number I have created a custom authentication file - backends.py

```
class EmailOrPhoneModelBackend(ModelBackend):

#This is a ModelBacked that allows authentication with either a username or an email address.
    
    def authenticate(self, username= None, password=None, **kwargs):
        
        if '@' in username:
            kwargs = {'email': username}
        elif re.search("^0?[5-9]{1}\d{9}$",username):   #optional
            kwargs = {'phone':username} 
        try:
            user = NewUser.objects.get(**kwargs)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except NewUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id): #username replaced with id
        try:
            return NewUser.objects.get(pk = user_id)
        except NewUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

and I have modified my settings accordingly as :

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "adminUser.NewUser"
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['adminUser.backends.EmailOrPhoneModelBackend',
                            'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',]
```

However, when I try to make the migrations I am getting the following error:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'adminUser.NewUser' that has not been installed
```

I have added the app 'adminUser' in the list of INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py also. I have also gone through the similar questions asked earlier but none of them have helped. Am not sure what is causing the issue and how it can be resolved. Thanks for your time in advance.

Below is the full stack trace of the error I am facing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\envs\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 178, in get_model
    return self.models[model_name.lower()]
KeyError: 'newuser'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\envs\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 157, in get_user_model
    return django_apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, require_ready=False)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\envs\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 211, in get_model
    return app_config.get_model(model_name, require_ready=require_ready)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\envs\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 180, in get_model
    raise LookupError(
LookupError: App 'adminUser' doesn't have a 'NewUser' model.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Documents\AysleAdmin\adminPanel\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Documents\AysleAdmin\adminPanel\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\envs\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\envs\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\envs\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\envs\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\envs\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\envs\myEnv\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Documents\AysleAdmin\adminPanel\adminUser\models.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .backends import EmailOrPhoneModelBackend
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Documents\AysleAdmin\adminPanel\adminUser\backends.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\envs\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\backends.py", line 5, in <module>
    UserModel = get_user_model()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\envs\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 161, in get_user_model
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'adminUser.NewUser' that has not been installed
```

Comment: Does your adminUser directory contain \_\_init\_\_.py file?

Comment: @Shiny add the _full_ stack trace of the error to your question.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I have added the full stack trace of the error

Comment: @MarkMishyn Yes there is a `__init__.py` file in the adminUser directory

Comment: @Shiny I see in the traceback you have this line `from .backends import EmailOrPhoneModelBackend` in models.py, also in the backend you use `NewUser` which implies that it also imports the models. This is an issue because of this _circular_ import. Remove that import, you shouldn't need the backend in the models.py file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the traceback you can see the following lines:

```
File "C:\Users\DELL\Documents\AysleAdmin\adminPanel\adminUser\models.py", line 20, in <module>
  from .backends import EmailOrPhoneModelBackend
```

This means you import the backend in `models.py` for some reason (doesn't make sense the backend shouldn't be needed here). Next in the backend you also use `NewUser` which implies that it also imports `NewUser`, this essentially means both files try to import the other leading to a *circular* import issue (In the end you model doesn't end up getting loaded).

The solution is simply to remove the line `from .backends import EmailOrPhoneModelBackend` from `models.py`.